# My tables aren't showing even though i'm using the same role

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I created these tables on sql developer using the default role scott (which I enabled during Oracle 11gs installation)

However when I login from scott using sqlplus the tables don't show at all.

[image: using sql developer]

I even tried logging on using connect /as sysdba the tables still don't show up even though I'm connecting via the sysdba role.

[image: using sql plus]

I created these tables a week ago and  did not initially type the keyword commit when I created these tables however if that was the issue why are they still being displayed on SQL developer every time I log in. Also I think SQL developer auto commits changes when I close it.

And yes these aren't empty tables they do have data in them respectively.

My db is on my local machine and I'm using Oracle 11g so I don't understand what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Command commit is only for DML(insert, update, delete, merge, ...). After DDL you don't need anything like commit, it's persistent (in your case). Maybe you need to use prefix schema scott. to access the table

Comment: yeah but i created a table wouldn't i commit since i inserted brand new data .
The tables aren't empty they have information within them

Comment: `SCOTT` is a user (schema), not a role. Are you sure you are actually connecting to the same database from both clients? Check the connection settings, and if you're using a TNS alias (particularly from SQL\*Plus) get the matching connection details from you `tnsnames.ora` file.

Comment: When you created the table, did you create it with those 4 rows and then add the additional rows with insert statements by chance? If so, I'm guessing that the later insert statements simply weren't committed, and therefore never saved to the table. To test, you can try inserting the rows again (doesn't matter if its from SQL Developer or SQL Plus,) then commit the inserts. Once committed, you should be able to query those rows from both SQL Developer and SQL Plus.

Comment: what user are you logged in as on SQL Developer, is it scott?

Comment: tab has this predicate under the covers =  where "A5"."OWNER#" = "A4"."USER#" .. what happens if you select * from dba_tables - do you see your tables then?

Comment: @cdb_dba [`tab` is a built-in view](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/TAB.html#GUID-CF8D9339-13B4-40BB-A21E-EF8F36FF35AB), though it's recommended not to use it anyway. The OP is only looking in the data dictionary, not within the tables they created, so doesn't matter if they have any rows in them. It would be better to query `user_tables` if connected as `SCOTT`; or if checking `dba_tables` as `SYS`, to check the owner.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson! I've never really messed with those built-in views so I didn't recognize it, figured that tab was just a generic table name that OP created.

Comment: yes im logged into as scott on both of the softwares also if i try doing select * from wallmart_stores ; as per recommended it shows that no such table exists hence i don't think it exists in sqlplus
and it makes no sense since my local machine is running orcale 11g , essentially it should have the same database

Comment: (a) *check* that you are on the same database - you may have a local DB but that doesn't mean you're necessarily connected to that, you could still connect to a remote DB; and (b) check who owns those extra tables (via `all_tables` or `dba_tables` if you can see that).

Comment: i am actually surprised how both of my SIDS are different on sql plus and sql developer

is there way i can change my sqpl plus connection to connect to the orcl one

Comment: You haven't included how you are connecting now, or how you are now seeing different SIDs, or what's in your `tnsnames.ora` if you're using a TNS alias (explicitly with `@alias`, or by having `$TWO_TASK` or `LOCAL` set).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was that i was connected to the SID orcl on sql developer 
and my sql plus was connected to my SID that i named during the 11gs installation

ran this on sqlplus=

```
var OHM varchar2(100);
> EXEC dbms_system.get_env('ORACLE_HOME', :OHM);
> PRINT OHM // ---> ORACLE_HOME
```

to find my oracle 11gs home directory

there was a file called 'tnsnames.ora' it  was located at [Your_ORACLE_HOME]/Network/Admin.
Opened it using Notepad( any text editor should work )

In tnsnames.ora file found the service name which i entered into sql developer and changed the port which was mentioned in the .ora file

works like a charm now.

Here is  a link to a useful post that helped me achieve my conclusion

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121251/sqldeveloper-ora-12505-tns-listener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-co

credits to  Do Long Bien